# What is role of R9 resistor at input to OPAMP in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, input-offset-voltage

[image]

I guess it has to something with offset nulling but not getting how .Circuit shown is of instrumentation  amplifier.

Comment: It looks like it is to adjust common mode rejection at high frequencies - not DC.

Comment: i do not see a "this" resistor in the schematic ..... all resistors are labeled, please refer to the resistor by label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell it's nothing to do with offset nulling because of the capacitor- it has no effect (or rather the same small effect) at DC regardless of the position of the wiper.

\$R_C\$ is for offset nulling

\$R_{10}\$ adjusts the DC common-mode rejection

\$R_9\$ adjusts the AC common-mode rejection

Comment: ...please can you explain HOW R9 can influence the common mode gain? I rather think that R9 - together with C1 - improves the stability margin and the step response.

Comment: @LvW This is a classic circuit by the late Bob Pease. See [his app notes](https://i.imgur.com/zeMgd89.png) from [here](http://www.introni.it/pdf/Bob%20Pease%20Lab%20Notes%20Part%209.pdf). It's trimmed at a frequency of interest,  typically mains frequency. Variable +fixed capacitors would be better.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany ...thank you for the link. In the past, I have seen many contributions from R.P. but not this one. I`ll try to find it in the book. My comment was because I know that a well dimensioned  RC-series combination from the inverting terminal to ground will improve phase margin and step response (because the loop gain is lowered). But this is done - in most cases - for low overall gain values (large loop gain).